# How to mount binary image of emmc and read partition table

Tags: android, binary

Hi I got a emmc dump for an android tv, I have the bin file for the userarea which I want to analyse and learn, there’s 2 think I want to first learn how to do. 1: I want to know how to mount the binary bin file. 2: I want to know how to see the partition table of the binary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.